# Passing a Date as a Parameter to a Custom Function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having an issue with the following function I am creating and do not understand why. It works if I define the date in the function, however will not work when I pass the date in. Does the variable type change or need to be defined somehow i.e. Function Date as Date

As the first part has been solved for this case, the issue now is showing at a higher part of the function. I am attempted to increment through today to today + 30. It seems this is not the correct way to go through the calendar. What is the proper way to do this?

```
function one(){
  var Today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var PlanningDate = new Date();
  var PlanningDay = "blank";

  for (i = 0; i<31; i++){
    PlanningDate = Today + i;  
    PlanningDay = DayString(PlanningDate).slice(0,3);
...
}

function DayString(DateIn){
    var ADate = new Date;
    ADate = DateIn;
    var DayOfWeek = ADate.getDay();
    //DateIn.getDay();
    console.log(ADate);
    console.log(DayOfWeek);
    switch (DayOfWeek) {
    case 0:
      return "Sunday";
    case 1:
      return "Monday";
    case 2:
      return "Tuesday";
    case 3:
      return "Wednesday";
    case 4:
      return "Thursday";
    case 5:
      return "Friday";
    case 6:
      return "Saturday";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam. With the exception of the fact that you forgot the closing `}`, this code works as is. It also works if I remove `ADate` and replace all references to it with `DateIn`. In order to help the community understand your problem and suggest a solution, it's best to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Try adding a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which succeeds in one case and fails in the other.

Comment: About `It works if I define the date in the function, however will not work when I pass the date in.`, if your showing script is used for `however will not work when I pass the date in.`, in this case, I think that it is required to know the value of `DateIn`. If the value of `DateIn` is the date object, I think that your script works. But if the value of `DateIn` is not the date object, I think that an error occurs at `var DayOfWeek = ADate.getDay();`. How about this?

Comment: The } bracket was missed when pasting the code over and exists in the implemented code. DateIn is a Date object, I believe. I have edited to add the parent function details. 

    var PlanningDate = new Date();

PlanningDay = DayString(PlanningDate).slice(0,3);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function DayString(DateIn) {
  const dA = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return dA[new Date(DateIn).getDay()];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This resolved the issue. I like this approach as well instead of the switch, case since it is much less code. This aspect is part of a larger function that still seems to have an issue. I will edit my question to include this.